# Cardinality of a group after knowing about complement of some of its normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $N$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ and $G\setminus N$ is finite, is $G$ finite?

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Firstly, we get $[G : N]$ is finite , but I have tried in many ways to show that $N$ is finite, but don't know whether I am in right or wrong path .

I can't think of counter examples also, any help is warmly appreciated .

Comment: $G$ is the disjoint union of some classes $g_i N$ for a family $(g_i)$ of elements of $G$. That should help you

Comment: You get that $G$ is finite iff $N$ is finite and that's all you can conclude.

Comment: @QiaochuYan: I don't think that's right. Note that it's the set-theoretic complement, not the quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x\notin N$, then $xN\cap N=\varnothing$; that is, $xN$ lies in the set-theoretic complement of $N$. But it is easy to verify that $xN$ is bijectable with $N$.

Note that you don't actually need to assume $N$ is normal; it is enough that it be a proper subgroup.